# Virtual Box, full screen?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I get Virtual Box go full screen, as of now I am getting my guest OS in a small screen (640 x 480) type, even 'going full screen' doesn't make any difference ?

I want my guest OS to be of same screen size as my host OS !

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install the [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/06/17/install-guest-additions-for-a-better-virtualbox-experience/)

> VirtualBox has special software that
>   can be installed inside Windows, Linux
>   and Solaris virtual  machines to
>   improve performance and make
>   integration much more seamless. Among
>   the features provided by these Guest
>   Additions are mouse pointer
>   integration and arbitrary screen
>   solutions (e.g. by resizing the guest
>   window).

Comment: WOW ! .... seems like a different world ! ... Ubuntu and Vista are just like 2 webpages ! ....

Comment: What worked for me was, http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/25/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-linux-ubuntu-debian-fedora-opensuse-red-hat-and-more/

Comment: @ Nifle : Any other 'hidden tricks' in Virtual Box ? ;)